# Stuck trying to draw horizontal line in console emulator

Tags: winapi, rust

Windows, using Win32 API calls directly.

I am trying to create a windows app that emulates the behavior of a console app. So I am using Cascadia Mono, the nice new font that comes with Windows Terminal (makes no difference to my problem if I use Courier New or Consolas). The app that is asking me to write things is trying to draw a box using the line drawing characters. The horizontal line char it uses is u2500, the standard light horizontal line

[image]

In my app I have calculated the width and height for the font and draw each character one at a time in my WM_PAINT message handling

```
        for row in 0..ws.rows {
            for col in 0..ws.cols {
                let ch = sb.buffer[offset];
                trace!("paint {:?}", ch);
                offset += 1;
                if ch.ch != ' ' {
                    if ch.fg == Color::Reset {
                        SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(255, 255, 255));
                    } else {
                        let rgb = color(ch.fg);
                        SetTextColor(hdc, rgb);
                    }

                    let u = ch.ch.encode_utf16(&mut b);
                    trace!("ch = {0:0x} ", u[0]);
                    assert!(
                        TextOutW(hdc, col * ws.ch_width, row * ws.ch_height, u.as_ptr(), 1)
                            != 0
                    );
                }
            }
        }
```

(sorry that this is rust , not C++, but you can see what calls I am making). All works fine  but the horizontal lines come out wrong. Here is a screen shot of 3 screens stack on top of each other.

- Top is my app,
- next is the original console app in windows terminal
- Last a cut and paste of the text from Windows terminal into notepad.

[image]

You can see that in my app the dashes are chopped off at either end so I get a dashed line. You can also see that the top left corner abuts right up to the first 'k' in the real things but in mine there is a definite gap. Also note that the right hand side of the last 'k' on mine is chopped off by the invisible bounding box of the first dash.

I cannot reduce the character pitch in my code to squash the dashes together because then the other characters will overlap.

I am very much a novice at font and character handling so I am at a loss. I have checked and I am for sure emitting 0x2500 as the character. My naive expectation is that all the characters in a fixed pitch font are the same and that they all stay nicely inside that bounding box.

NOTE : that rust utf16 call is taking the character thats in utf32 format (rusts standard char internal representation) and converting it to utf16.

EDIT: here is a simple no code winforms c# app screen, the same text is copied from the console app and pasted into the text box. Note that the glyphs are full width

[image]

And here is chrome displaying the same chars, full width \e2\94\80 is utf8 for 2500. Seem everybody knows a trick I dont
[image]

Comment: You should look in to `ExtTextOutA`, specifically the `lpDx` parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-exttextouta

Comment: This doesn't look right. If you are writing a console application then handling `WM_PAINT` or calling `TextOutW` seem out of place. Those are for use by GUI applications. It would help to see a more complete [mcve]. As an aside, Rust's `char` type uses UTF-32. UTF-8 is used for strings and string slices.

Comment: Not sure, but I think this is because Terminal uses DirectWrite (directly or implicitely though the use of Xaml/WinUI, etc. modern Windows UI programming) to output the text. DirectWrite supports font features (ligatures, etc.). Cascadia has been specially designed with these features. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/getting-started-with-directwrite and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_font_feature_tag . Not sure you can do the equivalent with old Windows API.

Comment: @IInspectable I am writing  GUI app that emulates the console interface of a text ui abstraction library. I specifically want it to be a win32 gui app, thats my intent. So I create a window and draw directly on it.

Comment: @SimonMourier, all windows apps show the #2500 character full width (character map, font explorer, notepad,...). Also, as noted, the same thing happens with other fixed width fonts (Courier for example). I started to look at WT source , it for sure uses WPF

Comment: @SimonMourier here is a simple winforms app with a text box set to cascadia momo 22, paste the chars directly in (editied into the question).

Comment: @Andy, what should I adjust, I want all the chars to be evenly spaced. if I move the dashes closer together then I wont get that. Imagine text embedded at the end of the line, either I have to move it to the left or have a huge gap between the end of the line and the start of the text.

Comment: Actually, I've just test the standard Visual Studio windows C++ app template with a string that contains 0x2500 characters `TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, L"kkkkkk────────", 14);`, and it displays a long line. There's nothing to do, no magic. Do you have a reproducing project?

Comment: @SimonMourier knowing that, i can work it out. I mean knowing that simple win32 app gets the correct output is all I need. I just tried the same and it works. Its going to be really interesting to see what I have done wrong. I have a suspicion TY, TY

Comment: @SimonMourier - OK If I do TextOut character by character I get my result, but if I do the whole string I get the longer dashes, its not a spacing thing, one at a time I get 5 dashes with spaces, all at once I get 5 dashes with no spaces, occupies exactly the same horzontal space. I do char by char becuase I need to be able to specify fg / bk for each cell. I think I will ask another question now I know the cause

Comment: @SimonMourier https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189427/difference-when-rendering-horizontal-line-using-textout-char-by-char-vs-all-at-o if you interested,