# difference when rendering horizontal line using TextOut char by char vs all at once

Tags: winapi

I am writing a win32 low level gui app that emulates a console app. I use a fixed width font, my test uses Cascadia Mono, but I have the same issue with any fixed width font.

The console app is trying to draw a horizontal line using U2500 character.

I output the characters that app is passing me one by one. When I do that I get spaces between the horizontal lines, when I output in one call to textout those gaps are filled in.

I made this using the VS c++ windows app template and added this code to the WM_PAINT handling

```
        auto nHeight = -MulDiv(48, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
        auto hfont = CreateFont(
            nHeight,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            100,//200,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            DEFAULT_CHARSET,
            OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
            CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
            CLEARTYPE_QUALITY,
            FIXED_PITCH,
            L"Cascadia Mono"
            );
        TEXTMETRIC tm;
        SelectObject(hdc, hfont);

        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        auto str = L"kkkkkk─────k";
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, L"kkkkkk─────k", 12);
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            TextOut(hdc, i * tm.tmAveCharWidth, tm.tmHeight,  &str[i], 1);
        }
```

This displays

[image]

you can see that this is not due to me miscalculating the char cell width, the strings are exactly aligned , just there are some added pixels in the upper one, also notice some extra 'knobiness' where the joins are. V odd. Also note that the right edge of the last K before the line starts is slightly chopped off in the char by char one, but not in the all at once one.

So why am I doing it char by char, because I need to specify font weight, bg, fg for each cell.

Comment: Wonder if the same happens with a raster font, and/or with `DrawText`.

Comment: It's probably a ligature when you have two hyphens together. A feature of the font.

Comment: @JonathanPotter and so what should I do?

Comment: Group your calls to TextOut together so you render as much of the string as possible in one call. You only need char-by-char if you're actually changing the font/colors every character. It'll be a lot more efficient that way as well.

Comment: @JonathanPotter well I just tested in Windows Terminal and they can draw a continuous horizontal line with each dash a different color. I know that I can batch up similar items and plan to do that for optimization, but I cant do that if each dash is a different color. I guess I need to find out how they are rendering the text (DirectText I think)

Comment: @JonathanPotter old fashioned cmd can do it too, and word. I have a horrible feeling that I cannot do this with vanilla win32 calls :( - I am coding the real app in rust so I cannot call any fancy c++ apis (GDIPlus, DirectWrite,..)

Comment: Word uses DirectWrite (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/murrays/office-adopts-new-windows-display-technology). Color for each char can be achieved for a whole string using DirectWrite. It's not fancy, GDI(+) is more or less legacy. Most app use a string in memory and redraw it (or the part that's visible of course, eg: notepad, richedit, etc.) when something changes. Not sure why you don't do that too. Anyway, not sure why, but DrawText instead of TextOut seems to fix your 0x2500 character issue. Note you won't have the 'knobiness' and small spaces are slightly different.

Comment: @SimonMourier I am holding a large string in memory and drawing when it changes (by sending myself InvaidateRect, or when demanded by WM_PAINT). Its just that each char also has an set of attributes the say how it should be rendered. I am building a backend for a text user interface library (tui) in rust. That library renders to terminal screen on mac, linux or windows, I am writing a backend to render as native GUI. Anyway I will check out DrawText. You have been v helpful BTW

Comment: @SimonMourier woo hoo DrawText does it - ty v much.

Comment: @SimonMourier make it an  answer

Comment: @SimonMourier 'fancy' means 'not plain c'. I am coding in pure rust, i cannot call c++ interfaces

Comment: COM is perfectly usable in C and I think  in Rust, but I guess the issue which Rust is you must redefine all headers which is probably some piece of work.

Comment: @SimonMourier https://github.com/microsoft/com-rs/

Comment: Yes, you do have DirectWrite pre-defined here https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs/blob/0.3/src/um/dwrite.rs as well as other related stuff (but although more powerful it's more complex than GDI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using TextOut, you can use [DrawText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) which is a bit more hi-level, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    RECT rc;
    rc.left = i * tm.tmAveCharWidth;
    rc.top = tm.tmHeight;
    rc.right = rc.left + 50; // todo: make sure this is ok
    rc.bottom = rc.top + 100;
    DrawText(hdc, (LPWSTR)&str[i], 1, &rc, 0);
}
```

And it seems to fix the "lineness" of it, although it's not 100% exactly the same (there are some pixels that show a difference):

[image]